# How to set dynamic password in connectionstring using SqlCacheDependency

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am defining my connection string in the `web.config` as shown below. However my database password is reading from AWS key manager and I am using a keyword replace to my connection string.

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="Star.Database" />
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Star.Database" 
         connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;User Id=USER;Passwor=@Password@" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<caching>
    <sqlCacheDependency enabled="true" pollTime="1000">
        <databases>
            <add name="StarSQLCache" connectionStringName="Star.Database" />
        </databases>
    </sqlCacheDependency>
</caching>
```

There is a portion of my program that is using `SqlCacheDependency` as shown below. How do I set the connection string in the `SqlCacheDependency`? I am thinking of getting the connection string out first and do a replace with `@Password@` with my AWS Key Manager Key value.

```
  SqlCacheDependency dependency = new SqlCacheDependency("Star.Database", "Lookup");
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you go down the route you're thinking of, you could leave the password out of the connection string, initialise an [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder) (CSB) with what you have, and then add the password in the CSB. That way, any required character escaping is taken care of for you.

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie. So you are saying to use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder to add populate the connectionstring and then add into the SqlCacheDependency?